# The best way to assign default value to typed prop

Tags: typescript

For example I have this:

```
  class SomeClass{
    private font:GameConfFont;
    init = () => {
      this.font = data.game.font || <GameConfFont>{};
    }
  }
```

GameConfFont is:

```
declare interface GameConfFont {
  families: Array<string>,
  css: string,
}
```

I don't like that I have to explicitly cast the default value here, this `<GameConfFont>{}`, however if I don't, then TS complains about it. Is there any other, more elegant way to write it?

Comment: What version of TS are you on and what's your error? I am on TS 2.2.1 with `noImplicitAny` turned on and I don't have to do this.

Comment: Please post the interface definition of `GameConfFont`

Comment: GameConfFont is posted in question description.

Comment: And yes, I use TS 2.0.8, bundled in WebStorm. As a matter of fact, I am translating a huge JS project to TS and I intend to turn `noImplicitAny` on when I'm done translating all the modules.

Comment: Separate issue, but it's highly unlikely that `init` is going to work as you intend given the way you defined it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty object (`{}`) is not a valid `GameConfFont`. It is missing the required properties. Why would you want to hold an invalid `GameConfFont` in `this.font`? If you want the properties on `GameConfFont` to be optional, then declare them as such:

```
interface GameConfFont {
  families?: Array<string>,
  css?: string,
}
```

Another alternative might be to initialize `this.font` to null.

Comment: I am setting those properties later, but you're right, I should initialize them to null.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe declare your `GameConfFont` as class and use its constructor instead?

```
class GameConfFont
{
    constructor()
    {
        //Initialize default instance here
    }

    public name: string;
}

class SomeClass
{
    private font:GameConfFont;

    public init(data)
    {
       this.font = data.game.font || new GameConfFont();
    }
}
```